Exact Match Vector Search using Weaviate
I have set up my schema on Weaviate like so with a tag column and no vectorization since I will be providing the embedding/vector myself:
class_obj = {
    "class": "tag_embeddings",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "tag",
            "dataType": ["text"],
        },
    ],
    "vectorizer": "none",
    "tokenization": "field"
}
client.schema.create_class(class_obj)

I have uploaded two tags: 'Lilice' and 'Sustainable Lilice'.
Although I have set the tokenization type to 'field' where it doesn't split off words into seperate tokens, I still can not get an exact match for just 'Lilice' when I try to query for the vector like so:
where_filter = {
    "path": ["tag"],
    "operator": "Equal",
    "valueText": 'Lilice'
} 

result = (
    client.query
    .get('tag_embeddings', ['tag'])
    .with_additional("vector")
    .with_where(where_filter)
    .with_limit(1)
    .do()
)

Instead I get the vector for 'Sustainable Lilice' back. If anyone knows where I am going wrong or know how to do an exact match search for the valueText and its corresponding vector, please let me know. Thank you!

I moved the tokenization: 'field' in properties like so:
class_obj = {
"class": "tag_embeddings",
"properties": [
    {
        "name": "tag",
        "dataType": ["text"],
        "tokenization": "field"
    },
],
"vectorizer": "none"}

provides exact match for the tag column.

hi! Duda from Weaviate here. Glad you found the solution! Here is an academy unit we have that covers this topic: https://weaviate.io/developers/academy/py/tokenization/basics
